# How to response different responses to the same multiple requests based on whether it has been responded?

Tags: python, distributed-computing

Let's say my `python` server has three different responses available. And one user send three HTTP requests at the same time.

How can I make sure that one requests get one unique response out of my three different responses?

I'm using python and mysql.

The problem is that even though I store already responded status in mysql, it's a bit too late by the time the next request came in.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, if MySQL isn't handling your performance requirements (and it rightly shouldn't, that doesn't sound like a very sane use-case), 
consider using something like in-memory caching, or for more flexibility, Redis:
It's built for stuff like this, and will likely respond much, much quicker.
As an added bonus, it has an even simpler implementation than SQL.

Second, consider hashing some user and request details and storing that hash with the response to be able to identify it.
Upon receiving a request, store an entry with a 'pending' status, and only handle 'pending' requests - never ones that are missing entirely.